# How to abort a proof in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I was wondering if there is a way to abort a proof in Isabelle/jEdit?

I searched for commands such as "Reset", "Abort" but couldn't find it.

I know there is `Sorry`. But I am not sure if one uses `Sorry`, the theorem at hand is assumed to be true or abandoned. Also, `Sorry` does not seem to work in the `apply..done` mode.

Currently, I comment out the theorems that I can't prove. But it requires a lot of typing (four characters each in (* *)) to comment or uncomment something, which is kind of cumbersome.

So is there a standard/universal way to abort a proof in Isabelle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the command is `sorry` and it does work (but only) in apply style:

```
lemma 
  ‹False ∧ True›
  apply (rule conjI)
   apply auto
  sorry
```

About the actual question, `oops` aborts proofs, whether in apply style or not:

```
lemma 
  ‹False ∧ True›
proof -
  have True
    by auto
  oops
```

An `oops`-ed proof cannot be referenced later.

Comment: Note that there are very few reasons to actually use `oops`, especially in finished proof developments. It can sometimes be useful to demonstrate things, I guess.